# Django serves CSS files and Favicon but not images from root static when debug =false or in production

Tags: django, heroku, static, django-staticfiles

I have been working on a personal profile site and have an image for my cover page saved in my root static folder. I can see the cover image fine in the browser when debug is true but when debug is false or I am in production the file is a 404 error, nowhere to be found.

The root directory also has a CSS file (style.css) and a `favicon.ico` which both show up fine when debug is set to false or I am in production, it is just the image that doesn't show/work.

I also have a background image in the "Polls" app that shows up fine in both debug=false and production.

Here is an image of my file directory:

[image]

Here is my `settings.py` which, based on Django documentation and Heroku deployment documentation, should be configured correctly:

```
import os
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'NUNYABIZNESS'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
# DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
     'still-atoll-90110.herokuapp.com',
     'localhost',
     'www.dominicscotto.org',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myportfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myportfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
# 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = None


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

I tried calling the image from both the css:

```
body {
    background: white url("images/Cover_image.jpeg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and the head of the base.html:

```
<style> body { background-image: url(images/Cover_image.jpeg);} </style>
```

But it doesn't seem to be an issue with how I am calling for the image, it just isn't there in the browser.

When I run collectstatic it seems to be finding and grouping the files in "staticfiles" correctly:

Directory showing statifiles

[image]

I believe it has something to do with the image being in the root static folder but I am not clear why Django doesn't like it there vs. in a specific app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Django 2.1 and Python 3.7.0

Comment: Django doesn't server static files if debug is set to False.This has to be done by the web server.

Comment: I have read this as well but when I run collectstatic locally some static files work like the css, the favicon, and the background image at /polls/ but specifically not the Cover_image.jpeg. I have also tried in production on Heroku and it does't work there either.

Answer (score 0):

as in official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/):

```
    In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL
    for the given relative path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE.

    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

and I think that in css you must use real path, Django doesn't serve css files with django template system. In your example, it would be

```
    body {
        background: white url("static/images/Cover_image.jpeg");
        ...
    }
```

also, you can check the availability of your static files on production just use right path, that will start with *static/* in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Cover_Image.jpeg has a capital I in image which was not what I had in my css or head file. A case of missed capitalization due to bad naming convention.

I have changed Cover_Image.jpeg to cover_image.jpeg and in my CSS I'm using:

```
background: white url("images/cover_image.jpeg");
```

I also had to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --clear
```

for Django to catch these static files with Debug set to false